# Automating the download of redhat for kickstart

Tags: linux, unix, automation, redhat

I'm trying to work on a project to automate the kickstart images however i'm stuck on my first subtask.

The download links for redhat downloads look something like the bellow:
[https://access.cdn.redhat.com//content/origin/files/sha256/12/mkwosis89j9f8ef53ad7365f2997d42d4f83ccuwodjsl/rhel-server-7.3-x86_64-dvd.iso?*auth*=148102836_3974432975fa9f10e716c4a38928db](https://access.cdn.redhat.com//content/origin/files/sha256/12/mkwosis89j9f8ef53ad7365f2997d42d4f83ccuwodjsl/rhel-server-7.3-x86_64-dvd.iso?_auth_=148102836_3974432975fa9f10e716c4a38928db)

This becomes a problem because i can't know what the sha and the auth code are going to be before hand i can't just modify this url in bash, i need to have a way of going to the Latest downloads page and follow the link.

Anybody know how what i can use to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't even work if you could get the sha etc. up front; they expire links periodically and you have to regenerate them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will be wasting a lot of bandwidth for each installation. Have you considered creating a local repository of ISO's? You would need to add the latest ISO when it is released. Check out this link for creating ISO repositories.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/redhat-centos-fedora-linux-setup-repo.html